# Compiling LightScreen on Linux Mint 18.1

Tags: compiling

I am having issues compiling a claimed to be Linux compatible application on Linux Mint 18.1. The application in particular is called Lightscreen. Everything has gone smoothly besides using the `make` command.

Here is the command process I have done so far:

I had to first install QT 5.7 because it wouldn't work with any other version unless I used an older version of lightscreen, as I would get this result:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: x11extras
```

So I went ahead and installed QT 5.7 which is claims to support in the most recent update, and this is the output:

```
nicholas@LinuxNick ~/bin/lightscreen $ /home/nicholas/.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/bin/qmake
Project MESSAGE: This project is using private headers and will therefore be tied to this specific Qt module build version.
Project MESSAGE: Running this project against other versions of the Qt modules may crash at any arbitrary point.
Project MESSAGE: This is not a bug, but a result of using Qt internals. You have been warned!
nicholas@LinuxNick ~/bin/lightscreen $
```

Suspecting everything was fine since there was no error messages but instead general Project messages, I continued. I ran make and there were my first errors.

```
In file included from tools/screenshot.cpp:45:0:
tools/screenshot.cpp: In member function ‘void Screenshot::save()’:
tools/screenshot.cpp:250:34: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
             result = Screenshot::Success;
                                  ^
tools/screenshot.cpp:260:79: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
   result = (QFile::rename(mUnloadFilename, fileName)) ? Screenshot::Success : S
                                                                     ^
tools/screenshot.cpp:260:79: error: expected ‘:’ before numeric constant
tools/screenshot.cpp:262:34: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
             result = Screenshot::Success;
                                  ^
Makefile:5959: recipe for target 'screenshot.o' failed
make: *** [screenshot.o] Error 1
```

Am I doing something wrong? I am kinda new to compiling stuff on linux and while I compiled quite a few programs, I still haven't gotten the hang of stuff and how things are supposed to be compiled. A step by step guide would be helpful, but it doesn't have to be one, especially if it isn't needed.

Please, help, and thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am now experiencing a different problem.
When I run `make`, this is the output:

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DUGLOBALHOTKEY_NOEXPORT -DAPP_VERSION=\"2.5\" -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_X11EXTRAS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CONCURRENT_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -Itools/UGlobalHotkey -Itools/UGlobalHotkey -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtMultimedia -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtGui/5.7.1 -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtGui/5.7.1/QtGui -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtX11Extras -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtSql -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtConcurrent -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/5.7.1 -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/5.7.1/QtCore -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I../../.Qt/5.7/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o os.o tools/os.cpp
tools/os.cpp: In function ‘QPair<QPixmap, QPoint> os::cursor()’:
tools/os.cpp:131:23: error: could not convert ‘QPoint(0, 0)’ from ‘QPoint’ to ‘QPair<QPixmap, QPoint>’
     return QPoint(0, 0);
                       ^
Makefile:5657: recipe for target 'os.o' failed
make: *** [os.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from `<X11/X.h>` (only included when compiling to Linux). It defines the following macro:

```
#define Success 0
```

This interferes with an enum member of the same name, `Screenshot::Result::Success`.

To fix this, open tools/screenshot.cpp, and find the following lines:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    #include <QX11Info>
    #include <X11/X.h>
    #include <X11/Xlib.h>
#endif
```

After the include for X.h, add an `#undef Success`. This removes the conflicting macro.

Comment: I edited the question with additional information. This is after applying your fix. It got rid of that error, but I am still experiencing an issue. In QtCreator, this is the only error in the output. Thanks, by the way. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Nevermind, I had a screwed up build. I re-installed Lightscreen, did your fix, and it seemed to have worked just perfectly fine. Thank you so much.